# JavaScript Date inside a Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i'm new to Web developing and i've encoutered an issue while i was testing some simple stuff.
Here i have some data in Sql datetime format in UTC gtc inside a simple database:

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP7Da.png)

So I created a Kendo Grid to format the data (and appending UTC at the end of each date) and it correctly shows:
[Correct Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D8Qz.png)

The problem occurred when i try to use the built in Date type of js to convert the UTC datetime into the local datetime:

[Unexpected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QEP9.png)

For some reason the first row of the grid is converted to a different timezone of the other rows.
This is the code that i used to fetch and format the table.

```
 $scope.mainGridOptions = {
        pageable: true,
        editable: true,
        sortable: true,
        dataSource: {
            pageSize: 5,
            transport: {
                read: function (e) {
                    $http.get('/GetScheduler')
                        .then(function success(response) {
                            e.success(response.data)
                        }, function error(response) {
                            alert('something went wrong')
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        "id": {
                            editable: false
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        },
        columns: [{ field: "id", title: "ID", width: "100px" },
                  { field: "Current_Time", title: "Time of Request", template: '#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(Current_Time), "dd/MM/yyyy h:mm")#' },
                  { field: "Selected_Time", title: "Scheduled Time" , template: '#= Selected_Time+" UTC" #'}, 
                  { field: "Description" },
                  { command: "destroy", width: "100px" }]
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are seeing a different time zone. It looks like you are seeing the same time zone shifted an hour due to the dates.

> Since 1996, European Summer Time has been observed between 01:00 UTC (02:00 CET and 03:00 CEST) on the last Sunday of March, and 01:00 UTC on the last Sunday of October; previously the rules were not uniform across the European Union

[Check here for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time).